# How to play IMFMediaSample in media foundation?

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I am able to extract samples out of a video using the readSample method. Now how can I play the data present in those samples? Or how to play IMFSample ?

Answer (score 1):

Sample `IMFSample` is a block of data, such as video frame or a chunk of audio sequence. This is a tiny piece of data to be played alone. The API addresses more sophisticated playback scenarios, such as where playback is a session where one or more streams are streamed in sync.

Be sure to check [Getting Started with MFPlay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318791%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN to see how playback is set up with Media Foundation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .. But i need to read a video file in chunks (or Samples or mediaBuffer) and play it using media foundation library. Like the way it happens in streaming over the internet where video is send in pieces over to the client. Please help in this regard or suggest any alternative other than IMFSamples.

Comment: MF creates a pipeline for playback, so you need a source which generates data http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms697527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Having individual buffers on hands, you will need to create custom source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms700134%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Roman, apparently you are some MVP, etc... But your every answer is an MSDN link to Media Foundation. Do you really think that we were not able to find it on our own a long time ago before posting questions here? Media Foundation is pretty useless, the technology is extremely complex and not flexible. MS from the VFW days are creating one worse technology than the other... DShow, WMF... The next one will probably require 10 developers and 6 months just for rendering one frame which will be absolutely non-accessible from the user mode. So, some concrete answers would be so appreciated.

Comment: @user1764961: most of the questions fall into two categories: `1` poster were indeed unable to find direct answers on MSDN, `2` poster does not mention what he already found making anyone reading his question follow him with MSDN search which just makes no sense.

Comment: 3 you don't really know the answers.

Comment: @user1764961: yes this is the case with your questions, I will make a note to not respond to them

Comment: I guess, I'll survive without answers like: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms697062(v=vs.85).aspx