# Present IMFSample

Tags: wpf, media, ms-media-foundation, slimdx

I'm working on a WPF project that need to use Media Foundation to capture video from webcam.
Now I can get IMFsample from webcam everytime I want, I had used SLimDX to get IMFMediaBuffer (get it from IMFSample) to IDirect3DSurface9 pointer and set it to back buffer of D3DImage. It's work great on PC but windows Tablet.

This is the error message I got when run on Tablet:

*The GPU device instance has been suspended. Use GetDeviceRemovedReason to determine the appropriate action.*

So Do you know another way to present IMFSample to UI.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to play IMFMediaSample in media foundation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719338/how-to-play-imfmediasample-in-media-foundation)

Comment: how I can use MFPlay to play IMFSample or play webcam device?. Please help.